# Get data from the last day of the month without the use of loops or variables

Tags: sql-server, database

I wrote a query that should select the last record of each month in a year. I'd like to create a View based on this select, that I could run later in my project, but unfortunately I can't use any while loops or variables in a view command. Is there a way to select all these records - last days of a month in a View that I can use later?

My desired effect of the view:

[image]

The query that I'm trying to implement in a view:

```
DECLARE @var_day01 DATETIME;
DECLARE @month int;
SET @month = 1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable2;
CREATE TABLE #TempTable2 (ID int, date datetime, INP2D float, INP3D float, ID_device varchar(max));
WHILE @month < 13
BEGIN
SELECT @var_day01 = CONVERT(nvarchar, date)  FROM (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM data
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(nvarchar, date)) = '59'
AND
MONTH(CONVERT(nvarchar, date)) = (CONVERT(nvarchar, @month))
ORDER BY date DESC
 ) results
ORDER BY date DESC;

INSERT INTO #TempTable2 (ID, date, INP2D,INP3D,ID_device) 
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE DATEPART(MINUTE, CONVERT(nvarchar, date)) = '59'
AND
MONTH(CONVERT(nvarchar, date)) = (CONVERT(nvarchar, @month))
AND
DAY(CONVERT(nvarchar, date)) = CONVERT(datetime, DATEPART(DAY, @var_day01))
ORDER BY date DESC
PRINT @var_day01
SET @month = @month +1;
END


SELECT * FROM #TempTable2;
```

Comment: You say you want the 'last record of each month' but your query actually returns all records where the minute is `59` within each month, which causes the multiple rows for some months you can see in your screenshot as well as a few other immediately obvious issues.  What are you actually trying to achieve here, as your query doesn't match your question at all...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are actually just after the single most recent row for each month, there is no need for a `while` loop to achieve this.  You just need to identify the `max` `date` value for each month and then filter your source data for those for those rows.

One way to achieve this is via a `row_number` window function:

```
declare @t table(id int,dt datetime2);
insert into @t values(1,getdate()-40),(2,getdate()-35),(3,getdate()-25),(4,getdate()-10),(5,getdate());

select id
      ,id_device
      ,dt
from(select id
           ,id_device
           ,dt
           ,row_number() over (partition by id_device, year(dt), month(dt) order by dt desc) as rn
     from @t
    ) as d
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: The answer you provided is great and it works, but I have an another problem that I didn't address in the post. I have different devices that correspond to the ID_device row, my goal is to get all of the most recent rows of each month, from each of the unique devices. In your query - I get the most recent data of each month, but only from the most recent device that sent the data. Is there a way to modify the query, so that it also selects all of the records where the ID_device is unique?

Comment: @Xarxes  Updated to include the `id_device` grouping

Answer (score 0):

You can add a simple `where` to your `select` statement, in `where` clause you will add one day to the `date` field and then `select` the `day` from the resultant `date`. If the result `date` is `1` then only you will `select` that record

the `where` clause for your query will be : `Where Day(DATEADD(d,1,[date])) = 1`

Comment: This will not work if there is more than one record on the last day of the month, as is clearly the case in the OP's screenshot

Comment: Ohh, I missed that part. Also my answer is about last day of the month.  So missed it completely.
In this case then we need to use Rank() function in the select with partition on month & year  RANK()(PARITITION BY Month(date), YEar(date) order by date desc) and select the records where Rank is 1